# mvn commands stuck the build when run with /bin/bash -c

Tags: bash, sh

I am running below command in Jenkins execute shell. All other commands working fine when run with -c and using &&. But along with those commands i need to run the mvn command with different arguments.But somehow after execution the build gets stuck and kept running in Jenkins.

```
/bin/bash -c "pwd && mvn clean install test -Dsuite=\"suitename\" -Dbrowser=\"firefox\" -Dplatform=\"linux\"  && whoami"
```

whoami command does not run. Also mvn command with all parameters triggers the build but it gets stuck. 
I think there is some syntax issue. I am not good in shell script and have spent a lot of time on it.
Can anyone please help to fix the syntax issue or any other way to execute the mvn commands

Comment: if **whoami** does not get executed then it probably is because the middle command fails. You need to fix the build. You dont have any variables here, can you try to enclose all the command in single quotes and remove the escaping of the double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exact purpose, sequence of Your commands and if mvn command ends up correctly but have You tried single quotation, so You can omit escaping quotes inside:

```
/bin/bash -c 'pwd && mvn clean install test -Dsuite="suitename" -Dbrowser="firefox" -Dplatform="linux" && whoami'
```

Comment: Can anybody please help me on this, i am really stuck here